# 0,1 binary polynomial programming

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-programming, quadratic-programming

Is there a mathematical optimization branch that explicitly tries to optimize this (type) problem?

$$\eqalign{
  & \min   \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {(J*s[i] + {J_1}*s[i]*s[i + 1] + {J_2}s[i]*s[i + 1]*s[i + 2] + ... + {J_m}s[i]*s[i + 1]*...s[i + m])}   \cr 
  & s[i] \in \{ 0,1\} \quad \forall i \in \{ 1,2...,N + m\}  \cr} $$

Currently, I only know things about Mixed integer programming (and its implementation using Gurobi)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the $s_{i}$ are integers, there are reformulations of integer polynomial terms that result in mixed-integer (linear) programs, at the cost of introducing additional variables and constraints. Fred Glover has a sequence of papers to that effect in the mid-to-late 1970s, and subsequent work has built upon it.

For example:

[Fred Glover, "Improved Linear Integer Programming Formulations of Nonlinear Integer Problems", Management Science, 22(4), 455-460, 1975.](http://leeds-faculty.colorado.edu/glover/fred%20pubs/69%20-%20Improved%20Linear%20Integer%20Programming%20Formulations%20of%20Nonlinear%20Integer%20Problems%20_%20%20Fred%20Glover.pdf)

Comment: oh, thank you very much. Do you mind provide me with a link or a name of one of the paper? Thank you:)

Comment: If it's useful, upvote my answer. One big problem we have is that people post useful answers to questions, and then the answers are not upvoted, which discourages users from contributing.

Comment: Actually, I will not hesitate to up vote if I have enough reputations :)